# Oracle: Error al realizar diferentes updates sobre el editor Lextedit

Tags: oracle, update, caracteres

De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Usando el editor **Lextedit**, quiero realizar diversos updates a varios registros, pero cuando intento ejecutar mi selección me manda error:

> 'Error executing command - Status <-2147483648> - Text <ORA-00933: SQL
> command not properly ended>'

Mi texto es:

```
update base_taxis set placa=NUM0818,driver=1290,where carro=23;
update base_taxis set placa=NUM0823,driver=1180,where carro=12;
```

---

Corrección: (gracias jachguate)

```
update base_taxis set placa='NUM0818',driver=1290 where carro=23;
update base_taxis set placa='NUM0823',driver=1180 where carro=12;
```

Al ejecutar la selección obtenemos el error:

> 'Error executing command - Text <ORA-00911: invalid character'

Comment: El valor a asignar a `placa`, que es una cadena de texto, debe ir entre comillas simples (apostrofes):

Answer (score 0):

El valor a asignar a `placa`, que es una cadena de texto, debe ir entre comillas simples (apostrofes).

También hay una coma de más, entre el último campo asignado (`driver`) y la cláusula `where`, esa coma hay que removerla.

```
update base_taxis set placa='NUM0818',driver=1290 where carro=23;
update base_taxis set placa='NUM0823',driver=1180 where carro=12;
```

Comment: Cierto, corrección realizada, sigo teniendo el mismo error.

Comment: Había otro error, actualicé mi respuesta. Agradezco que dejes la pregunta como estaba originalmente, si no, vamos dejando mi respuesta fuera de contexto.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, caray... mil disculpas por los errores, esa corrección de sintáxis ya está realizada, aún con el error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema fue que la primer línea (no sé por qué) es la del error, ejecuté todo como un 'script' desde el panel de ejecución del editor y listo, realizó las N tareas solicitadas, a excepción de la primera línea... Al menos esa se realiza sin problemas.